# How to sum fields value from Observable with Angular 4 Firestore array

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

I'm new in Cloud FireStore and have been searching for many days without results, for a simple solution on how can I sum some fields value of an array coming from Observable Angular Firestore. I have a list of rows and I want sum and have the column total, here is part of my code:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private router: Router,  private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.negocio = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['negocioId']
    this.movtosCollectionRef = this.afs.collection('movtos', ref => ref.where('empresa', '==', this.negocio));


    this.movtos$ = this.movtosCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(action => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Movtos;
          const id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });


    });   
  }
```

In my template I make the browse :

```
      <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of movtos$ | async" [class.completed]="item.completed">
                <td>{{ item.indate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.concepto }} </td>
                <td>{{ item.tipomov }} </td>
                <td>{{ item.inuser }} </td>
                <td>{{ item.importe |  currency:'USD':true:'3.2-2' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" (click)="editaEmpresa(item.id)" tooltip="Edita Movimiento" placement="top"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

                </td>

            </tr>   

        </tbody>
```

And I want to get the sum of item.importe field.
Does any body know how to do this?
Best regards, 
Caribesoft

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` on the Observable to return the sum. eg

```
getSum(): Observable<number> {
    return this.observable
       .map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.value, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your response, but where do I get "this.observable" ? I tried with this.movtos$ but it does not work.

Comment: Are you getting the response as a promise? Then you  can use `Observed.fromPromise()`

Comment: I'm trying this -> getSum(): Observable<number> {
       return this.movtos$
       .map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.importe, 0));
  }  but I get  
TOTAL: [object Object]

Comment: Can you try and log what the object holds?

Comment: Hi, thank you, I resolved using Subscription this way :   this.totalSubscription = this.movtos$.subscribe((list:any) => {
  this.total = 0; 
  let fixedLength = list.length || 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < fixedLength; i++) {
        this.total += list[i].importe;
     }   
}